# Как установить 2 разных шрифта на кнопку?

Tags: android

[image]

Мне нужно как на этой картинке в кнопке установить 2 разных шрифта. Скажи пожалуйста как это сделать. Спасибо заранее

Comment: сделать три отдельных вьюшки: фон и два TextView